# String formatting in C

Tags: c, string, formatting, string-formatting

I am new to C and I am currently working on string formatting. In particular how you would format decimals to have 2 leading places. Thus you would have 1, 20, 300 become 001, 020, 300. I understand there is %d but I haven't figured out a solution!

Comment: I hope it helps you: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Try `printf("%09d", number);`

Comment: Suggest posting more examples if @R Sahu comment is not sufficient.

Comment: `1`, `20` and `300` are three separate examples, right? If so, you might want to make that a bit clearer. Otherwise the three examples pasted together look like a long integer with thousand s separators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int one = 1;
    int two = 2;
    int twenty = 20;
    printf("One: %03d\n", one);
    printf("Two: %03d\n", two);
    printf("Twenty: %03d\n", twenty);
}
```

Output:

```
One: 001
Two: 002
Twenty: 020
```

Comment: @Guillemo Welcome ! I think the main function need a  `return 0;` before the last bracket !

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: At first, I interpreted the example as you did, too, but now I think the long number with commas is really three examples of numbers that should be padded to three digits each, so the example is okay.

Comment: @MOehm: Oh; yes, I see.  That certainly makes more sense as a requirement, and is also trivially done with the code supplied by Guillermo.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Meninx: for better or worse (IMO, mostly for worse), C99 and later permits you to drop the `return 0;` at the end of `main()` and treats falling off the end of `main()` the same as if there was a `return 0;` there.  I don't like the special casing of `main()` that entails, but it is consistent with C++98 and later.  Personally, I plan to continue to write `return 0;` at the end of `main()` — the recommendations in [21st Century C](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025108.do) notwithstanding.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't know about that ! :)   I am from the old school  Great Thanks  and your comments are always valuable

Answer (score 0):

printf("%02d\n", 1);  // output: 01

printf("%03d\n", 1);  // output: 001

printf("%04d\n", 1);  // output: 0001

printf("%05d\n", 1);  // output: 00001

printf("%06d\n", 1);  // output: 000001

....